# how to stop the otto event propagation

Tags: android, broadcast, otto

Trying to use otto to replace our native event manager. One use case it has is the event could be subscribed by multiple listeners in different places, but only the first one received it should handle it and stops the this event's propagation.

Is this supported in otto, how to doit with otto?

Comment: Note that Otto has been discontinued by its developers. Consider using something else (greenrobot's EventBus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, something based in RxJava, `MutableLiveData`, etc.).

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare! good to know.